# Nested table in BIRT opens too meny db cursors, causing cursor error

Tags: birt, database-cursor, opentext, magellan

Im designing a report in BIRT, where I have 2 data sets and one parent table and under that a child table. For each parent row, I'm firing child table, so it's hitting database everytime. For example if I'm having 100 rows of parent records, for each I'm processing child table. So child table query is executed 100 times. Thus 100 cursors are opened, and after 4/5 runs I'm getting maximum cursor open error. Is there any better approach ?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of BIRT are you using?
Maybe you are hitting a bug:

https://github.com/eclipse/birt/issues/875

This was fixed in March 2022.